# How to quickly spot linearly dependent vectors in matrices without calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank, algebraic-independence

I have the following matrix:
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

I clearly see that the third row is the sum of the first two rows, hence a linear combination of the two; I so know that the rank of the matrix is 2.
If I look at the columns I know that one must be the linear combination of the other two, by doing calculations I know it is the third column. However, I would like to know if there's a quicker way to spot the LD column without having to do calculations?

Thank you in advance, this would be really time efficient for my exam.

Comment: Even spotting requires a minimum of calculation. And why not do a calculation.

Comment: One method is performing [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). But this requires some calculations still.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, you have to know what you are hoping for. The determinant of the matrix will be $0$ if and only if the columns are linearly dependent, but the determinant requires a calculation.

Comment: "*by doing calculations I know it is* **the third column**"  The third column being a linear combination of the first two does not preclude the first column being a linear combination of the second two.  It is incorrect to refer to it as "*the*" LD column as the article "the" implies some level of uniqueness.

Comment: *"If I look at the columns I know that one must be the linear combination of the other two, by doing calculations I know it is the third column."* If one column is a combination of the other two, it's likely that **every** column is a combination of the other two. In fact, if you can express one column as a linear combination of the others without zeroes in the coefficients, then it's easy to turn that equation around so that every column can easily be expressed as a combination of the others.

Comment: For instance with the rows, you've noticed that R3 = R1 + R2. Well, you can immediately turn that around to get R1 = R3 - R2, and R2 = R3 - R1.

Comment: As for being efficient in your mental arithmetic... take advantage of zeroes where they appear.  Here, trying to write the second column as a linear combination of the first and third for example, we notice that since the third column has a zero in the second position that we must have if $C_2 = a C_1 + b C_3$ that we must have $1 = a\cdot 2 + b\cdot 0$ and so $1=a\cdot 2$ and so $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and we are more than halfway done, almost immediately.  These steps didn't even need to be written down and can all be done in one's head.